# How to add row in AbstractTableModel through Jbutton in java swing

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing

I am doing abstract table using Eclipse and I am doing it on java swing. How can 
I add row through button?

I am using this table to do looping where the user input is store in the table with
`fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);` and later it will enter into database.

I create a class in my swing for table.

The method entering into the database is ink to my entity class (completed already).

The table will update after the user had key in each table cell (completed).

I had added in jcombobox to the table (completed).

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnNames = {"Account", "Discount",
        "Amount due",
        "Memo"
    };
    private Object[][] data = {
        {null, null, null, null}
    };

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        switch (c) {
            default:
            case 0:
                return String.class;
            case 1:
            case 2:
                return Double.class;

            case 3:
                return String.class;

        }
        //return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();

    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        // if (DEBUG) {
        System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                + " to " + value
                + " (an instance of "
                + value.getClass() + ")");
        //}

        data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

        //if (DEBUG) {
        System.out.println("New value of data:");
        printDebugData();
        //}
    }

    private void printDebugData() {
        int numRows = getRowCount();
        int numCols = getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }
}

final JTable AddBillTable = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
scrollPane.setViewportView(AddBillTable);

//for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++) insertRow();

TableColumn accountColumn = AddBillTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);


accountColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(JAccountComboBox));


String date = (String) JBillCombo.getSelectedItem();
String supplier= (String) SupplierJcomboBox.getSelectedItem();
String dueDate=(String) JBillDueDate.getSelectedItem();
String account=(String)JAccountComboBox.getSelectedItem();


for (int i = 0 ; i < AddBillTable.getRowCount() ; i++) {
    double discountAmount= 0.0;
    double amount1 = 0.0;
    String memo="";

    for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        account=(String)AddBillTable.getValueAt(i,0);
        discountAmount=(double)AddBillTable.getValueAt(i,1);
        amount1=(double)AddBillTable.getValueAt(i, 2);
        memo=(String)AddBillTable.getValueAt(i,3);
    }

    Bill1 e1 = new Bill1(date,account,supplier,amount1,discountAmount,memo,dueDate); 

    //insert into database
    e1.createBill();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: there are two reasons for `urgently needed` ---> 1. for better help sooner post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), 2. format you code, EDIT btw 3. question in this form and nature isn't answerable on SO

Comment: -1 : If you want something urgently, you might want to PAY someone to help you. Stack Overflow is not Tech Support/Private Tutor.

Answer (score -1):

Create the model class in the following fashion to add rows...

```
public class TableModelTest extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String[] columnNames = {"Account","Discount",
            "Amount due",
            "Memo"
          };

    private ArrayList<ArrayList> data;

    public TableModelTest(ArrayList<ArrayList> data){
        this.data = data;   
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return data.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex);
    }

    public void addRow(ArrayList row){
        data.add(row);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

Now on button click you need to simply call `addRow()` method of TableModelTest class.

As i can see the code which you have added, you are using array of array to maintain the data for model. I would suggest you to not to use array of array while go for List of List because your JTable would be expanding at runtime and same thing you can see in my code sample.
I believe it will help you a lot.

Comment: fireTableDataChanged(); is wrong notifier search for fireTableRowsInserted